# Inlining of virtual function when I can specify the actual type of the object as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inlining

I have a virtual class `Calculator` and an example implementation `MyCalculator` of that class.

```
template <class T>
class Calculator{
    virtual void op1() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class MyCalculator : public Calculator{
    void op1(){ do_something(); }
};
```

When I use `op1()` as demonstrated in the following function, the compiler can of course not inline `op1()` since it is virtual:

```
void calculate(Calculator* calc){
    calc->op1();
}
```

In some cases, however, I know the actual type of `calc` AND I d like to inline it for performance reasons. So I think about the following idea:

```
template <class C>
void calculate(C* calc){
    calc->op1();
}
```

I would call this function then as follows:

```
Calculator c1 = new Calculator();
calculate(c1); // no inling possible in calculate(...)

MyCalculator c2 = new MyCalculator();
calculate(c2); // inlining possible in calculate(...) ?
```

In the first example, inlining is not possible, but I think in the second example, `op1()` of `MyCalculator` should get inlined inside `calculate()`.

Is my assumption true?

Comment: For all the compiler knows, `calc` in `calculate<MyCalculator>` points to some class derived from `MyCalculator` that overrides `op1`. So it still has no choice but to perform virtual dispatch. A compiler doing whole program optimization might have enough information to inline all calls - but barring that, I don't see opportunities for optimization here.

Comment: Is your first statement true? I would expect not, since `op1` is not virtual in `MyCalculator`.

Comment: `op1` is too virtual in `MyCalculator`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mark a virtual function as `final` in C++11 which means that you cannot override it in a more derived class. Then the compiler can inline this function. Otherwise the compiler cannot be assured that you are not calling it with a more derived type with a different override, therefore it cannot inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable LTO,

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization,

from what I've read (but not yet tested myself) LTO can direference virtual calls if the linker can detect the actual intended implementation and therefore at that time the linker can also decide to inline the function